# Нестандартная сортировка в DataGridView

Tags: c#, windows, sql-server

Необходимо реализовать сортировку данных в Datagridview, который связан с базой данных SQL Server. Datagridview состоит из двух колонок. Сортировку нужно выполнить по первой колонке. В колонке строки типа "Brand1","Brand2" ещё "Brand1".  После сортировки должно быть так "Brand1","Brand1","Brand2". т.е. нужно строки сравнить и объединить в одинаковые группы .

Подскажите как можно выполнить такую сортировку?

Comment: DataGridView может сортировать данные по столбцам без дополнительных усилий со стороны программиста. Сортировка уже встроена в него. Опишите задачу как можно точнее (что и как Вы делаете). Приведите код, чтобы была не только понятна суть проблемы, но её также можно было воспроизвести.

Comment: Встроенная сортировка не работает. Нужно отсортировать по первому столбцу DataGridView, в котором содержаться строки. Работает сортировка только если написать в ручную: `dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns["Brand"], ListSortDirection.Descending);` но проблема тогда другая возникает, где разместить данный код, потому что он работает, если выполнить его к примеру по событию клика по datagridView. То есть получаем сортировку только по клику мыши а не сразу после загрузки.

Comment: Логично разместить код предназначенный для сортировки сразу после кода, который загружает данные. Тогда должны сразу отображаться отсортированные данные. А, вообще в подобных случаях, ИМХО, лучше сортировать сразу в SQL запросе (ORDER BY).

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вызывать метод `Sort` в обработчике события `DataBindingComplete`:

```
private void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender,
    DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns["Brand"], ListSortDirection.Descending);
}
```

Подписаться в конструкторе:

```
InitializeComponent();
this.dataGridView1.DataBindingComplete += dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete;
```

Comment: Пробовал уже почти все события dataGridView. Эффект тоже самый, исключение `Значение не может быть неопределенным`.

Comment: @Vladimir покажите каким способом вы загружаете данные в грид из sqlserver?

Comment: В dataGridView есть опция choose Date Source, а далее всё по умолчанию

Comment: То есть по умолчанию? DataSource вы каким типом заполняете? Нужно эе как-то проблему воспроизвести, а заполнять его можно многими способами. Лучше бы ваш код в дополнении к вопросу, конечно, посмотреть ;)

Comment: про какие типы вы спрашиваете? типы данных которые хранятся в БД? - это строки тип varchar, и первичный ключ id(int).                     Данные в datagridView попадают так:  выбираем опцию choose Date Source, далее выбираем источник, далее выбираем таблицу (строку соединения, методы, классы Visual Studia генерирует автоматически)

Comment: Воспроизвести эту проблему можно просто путём создания проекта Windows Forms, создать таблицу в SQL Server со строками, добавить dataDataGridView, затем соединиться с SQL Server через DataSourse, получить данные в dataDataGridVie и попробовать отсортировать.

Comment: @Vladimir сделал все как вы сказали. И мой метод работает.

Comment: @Vladimir Нужно обратить внимание на правильное указание имени колонки dataGridView1.Columns["Brand"]. В моем случае автоматически было сгенерировано имя: valDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.